# INSERTing millions of files into a table

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, innodb, mariadb-10.6

I archive millions of XML files (1-100MB each) in a table with the structure of

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
    ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    XML longtext COMPRESSED,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

INSERT INTO Data (ID,XML) VALUES ($id,LOAD_FILE('file.xml'));
```

The process is slow, around 2-5 inserts/second. The entire database would be too large for an SDD drive, and I create the database on a separate HDD, but I move the files in batches to an SDD drive to make the reading faster. Note that disk speed is not the rate-determining step, as XML data are hugely shrunk by compression.

I tried `InnoDB` to gain concurrent insert, but the size of InnoDB ibd is three times larger than ARIA/MyISAM, and InnoDB is much slower on HDD.

I tried `ROCKSDB`, but it cannot be created on a separate disk, as there is one single directory for all tables. Also, the memory management of ROCKSDB is terrible for such scenarios (or I could not find the proper configuration).

I did not try `ARCHIVE` engine performance since it needs `ID` to be in order.

My current solution is to INSERT concurrently to a temporary InnoDB table on SSD and then `INSERT INTO SELECT` from the InnoDB table to the ARIA table on HDD. The problem is the integrity and delay in emptying the InnoDB and starting the concurrent INSERT process.

I appreciate any possible solution.

Comment: Is `ID` `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  If not, how are the values set?

Comment: @RickJames `ID` is the unique identifier of the file and comes with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- InnoDB's `COMPRESSED` gives about 50% shrinkage of disk space.
- gzip (and most other file-based tools) compress down to about 33%.  So, it is better to shrink in the client instead of the server, even if they are the same machine.  Note: This requires storing into `LONGBLOB`, not `LONGTEXT`.  And it requires the clients to uncompress when reading.
- By moving compression to the client, inserting can use multiple processes (and CPU cores) to speed up the task.  Still, I would *guess* that 3 processes is perhaps the practical limit; the number of cores is definitely a limit.  (Using too many processes makes them stumble over each other, thereby decreasing overall efficiency.)
- Conclusion from above items:  To significantly speed up loading the database, have multiple processes, each compressing and inserting of one XML file into a table with `id` and `LONGBLOB`.
- If the XMLs are left as files, the OS can handle [de]compression.  (And probably the 33% metric applies.)  Meanwhile, the database table could have two columns:  `id` and `filename` (or path).
- For inserting/fetching a single compressed XML, each of the techniques will take about the same amount of elapsed time -- [un]compressing and I/O are the main factors.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **lot** of work to get all these files into the database.

Question: What are you going to *do* with them once they're in there?

If the answer is something like ...

> When X happens, I want to extract the XML into a file and then ..."

... then your solution is simple.  Don't do it!

That would be a classic case of incurring *lots* of overhead getting them *into* the database, followed by *more* overhead getting them *out* again, just to use them as the files they started off as.

If you do decide you need to keep them in the database, then ...
That's a very simple table structure and I *assume* you're only *ever* going to retrieve the whole "slab" of Xml in one go, based on the `id` column.  If you're going to do *anything else* then you should be thinking that you might need to extract those data that you want to filter by into simple columns.  Yes, there *are* fancy Xml-aware indexes these days, but they'll never perform as well as a single column with an index on it.

Comment: It is much easier to have a large number of files stored in a simple structured table rather than millions of files. For example, you can easily move them, compress them, and retrieve a range. No, I don't need to index XML structure. I just need to retrieve them by ID. And, no, they will not be extracted to file again. Their data are used directly from the database. Anyhow, these are all irrelevant; the question is about an efficient way to move a large number of files into a table.

Comment: @Googlebot "*It is much easier to have a large number of  files stored in a simple structured table rather than millions of files. For example, you can easily move them, compress them, and retrieve a range.*" - There is no difference in difficulty for these use cases for file management. It sounds like you're trying to use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail.

Comment: @J.D. you lost me. Moving millions of files to another disk is as simple/fast as moving three files of the ARIA table?

Comment: @Googlebot Yep. 100 GB of data = 100 GB regardless if you store them in 3 DB files or 1 million actual native files. 100% the same from a simplicity standpoint. There's obviously some minor repetition between more files, from a performance standpoint, but then you can just move them as a single file such as through a backup of the share, which is the equivalent of moving a database backup and probably the proper way to do either. And at the OS level, usually it's a file / folder reference that is changed which is just an immediate metadata change, which would be faster than moving DB files.

Comment: Database != File
Stop thinking of your database as files.  Your "database" is a running process that you interact with that just happens to have some files "under" it.  Only use database tools to work with database files.  Doing anything with them at the file system level is just asking for trouble (inconsistency, data loss, outages, etc.) 
Why would you "move" database files around on the same disk, anyway?  Let the DBMS worry about where /it/ wants its files to be.  "Moving" them elsewhere should be done with database tools (backup/restore, replication, etc.).